# Foreign key constraint fails because insert statement not yet committed (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a PHP script using [Doctrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29) 2 which does essentially the following:

```
$entityManager->transactional(function($em) {
    $foreignObject = new DoctrineEntities\ForeignTable();
    $em->persist($foreignObject);
    $em->flush();
    $aObject = new DoctrineEntities\A();
    $aObject->ForeignID = $foreignObject->ID;
    $em->persist($aObject);
    $em->flush();
});
```

I'm getting an integrity constraint violation:

> *a foreign key constraint fails (dbName.A, CONSTRAINT A_ForeignID FOREIGN KEY (ForeignID) REFERENCES `ForeignTable` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)*

My guess is that the constraint is checked before the commit, and it doesn't check to see whether an insert I made that hasn't been committed yet might make the constraint pass rather than fail. But I really do want these two insert statements wrapped in the same transaction. So what can I do?

**UPDATE**

I moved `$em->persist($aObject); $em->flush();` out of the transaction and I'm still getting the same error. Apparently, my guess was wrong... But then I really don't know what's causing the error.

---

***SQL Context***

Table **A**

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ForeignID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `A_ForeignID` (`ForeignID`),
  CONSTRAINT `A_ForeignID` FOREIGN KEY (`ForeignID`) REFERENCES `ForeignTable` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci
```

Table **ForeignTable**

```
CREATE TABLE `ForeignTable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Could you try to make a sample at SQLfiddle? If I'm not mis-reading it sounds like it should "just work".

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson | I've been trying to reproduce this problem strictly in mysql, but I haven't been able to. Maybe the problem is related to the way Doctrine handles transactions..?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code, but if you're using Doctrine, you may try flushing between the persists, so they don't get reordered.

Comment: I agree, this must be something within your application (or the ORM layer), because the basic order of the statements is fine.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson : What do you mean, `reordered`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name See my edit; I changed the pseudo-code to make it more similar to the actual thing.

Comment: Sorry, I neither know PHP nor that Doctrine thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to read about MySQL data integrity and [FKs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), then [Doctrine associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html), data integrity is checked by MySQL for InnodDB tables. What you're doing is not right, it should be

```
$entityManager->transactional(function($em) {
    $foreignObject = new DoctrineEntities\ForeignTable();
    $em->persist($foreignObject);

    $aObject = new DoctrineEntities\A();
    $aObject->setForeign($foreignObject);
    $em->persist($aObject);

    $em->flush();
});
```

Comment: I am working with an existing database schema. The `Doctrine associations` link you provide only documents how to use Doctrine to set up associations by creating a new database schema. Do you have any litterature concerning the case where the schema already exists?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was somewhere else completly unrelated to my question.. I'm going to accept getme's answer instead because accepting this answer really won't help anyone else here...